# Running an apk into a android emulator

Tags: docker, android-emulator

I have a android application project. I have a jenkins server , in which
, i launch a task to generate the apk.

Now, I am trying to run this apk into a android emulator, wihtout install the apk in phone.

Any suggestion to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to run application without install APK. even if you want run your app on android phone for testing you have to plugged that to PC and run it from your main device. notice : in second case you have to make your phone as developer mode. so your application will be install automatically in debugging mode.